# want to get the log from the git repository having details (date , time, gmt , file path , author) in same order and line

Tags: python, git

```
pr1 = subprocess.Popen( "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git log  --format=%ai%an --name-only --oneline HEAD" , cwd = os.path.dirname('C:/Users/Angular-GettingStarted/APM-Start' ), shell = False, stdout= logFile)
pr1.wait()
```

i m using this command but having issues

Comment: mention the issue you are getting.

Comment: Please read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that users can assist you more easily.

Comment: Could you please provide your traceback, and explain the problem you're trying to solve?